# How to dump internal session variables in tmux?

Tags: linux, tmux

I would like to get a value of *window_name* variable from within a tmux session.

```
showenv '#{window_name}'
```

Gives an error

> Unknown variable: #{window_name}

Any other form of specification of the variable name: *#window_name or {window_name}* quoted with single or double quotes gives the same error.

How can I get it's value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"showenv" won't work, because these are not environment variables at all. (While they might be similar things *in a shell script*, they actually live in completely separate worlds, a shell just pretends that environment variables are shell variables.) Also note that *neither* the `#` nor the `{…}` are not part of the variable name; they both only indicate an expansion itself.

To list all *format* variables, you can use `tmux display-message -a` or just read the list provided in the tmux manual page, under the "FORMATS" section.

```
$ tmux display-message -a
alternate_on=0
alternate_saved_x=0
alternate_saved_y=0
buffer_mode_format=#{buffer_size} bytes (#{t:buffer_created})
client_control_mode=0
```

To test expansions from command line, use `tmux display-message [-p] <text>`:

```
$ tmux display-message -p "This is #{window_name} in #{session_name}."
This is bash in 0.
```